# WooCommerce Tax Filter Not Working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I'm using the official docs here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce and their snippet below to create a threshold trigger so that orders below $110 are not taxed.  The problem is, WC()->cart->subtotal seems to always be 0 when this filter fires even with items in cart.  Any ideas / insight?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'big_apple_get_tax_class', 1, 2 );

function big_apple_get_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal <= 110 )
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

    return $tax_class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the subtotal like this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart_subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

From [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/class-reference/). So you will can do something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'big_apple_get_tax_class', 1, 2 );

function big_apple_get_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
    if ( $cart_subtotal <= 110 )
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

    return $tax_class;
}
```

Comment: Still returns zero, also get_cart_subtotal returns the markup in addition to the price.